# Windows 10 pro only standard user account

Tags: windows, windows-10-desktop

on windows 10 pro.
 I made a mistake yesterday, I changed the only account on my system from administrator to standard user account and now i cant do anything on my system e.g install applications and run some applications.
  I cant do any of them. I have no administrator right.

Comment: https://windowsreport.com/fix-deleted-administrator-account-accident/

Comment: Make me see the *programming* angle.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make another adminintrator account I think.